# How should this light fixture be connected?

Tags: wiring, light-fixture

Replacing kitchen light, house wiring to box: 2 white twisted together (neutral), 1 red (hot when switch is on), no ground. Fixture: 1 D shaped ridged wire, 1 smooth (round) wire, 1 ground wire. My guess on connections, D shaped fixture wire to white house wires, smooth (round) fixture wire to red house wire, fixture ground wire to metal fixture box? Is this right?

Comment: Wiring isn't usually referenced by shape. Please edit to post colors or a photo.

Comment: New Fixture wires are both brown, 1 D shaped ridged, 1 round and smooth, instructions with fixture state ridged to white house wire, smooth to black house wire.

Comment: *Edit* to post colors, please.

Comment: ... and please edit to post pictures as well. If you don't have enough rep to post pictures, post URLs of the pictures and someone will be along to edit them in.

Comment: If the fixture is for a standard screw-in (Edison) bulb, use an ohm meter/continuity tester between the socket shell (part with threads) and the wires. The wire connected to the shell is the neutral.

Comment: One conductor of "lamp cord" is often ridged in such a way so that a cross section of the conductor with insulation has the shape of a letter "D". I think this is what Lee means. The convention is that the ridged conductor is intended to connect to the circuit neutral (white). I think Lee is correct in his wiring surmise. Lack of a ground to the box is a worry, though. A picture would help see if there is a ground from an AC or MCAP feed.

Answer (score 1):

When a light fixture has two wires of the same color it usually means that polarity isn't important. However, the ridges/ribs may indicate a neutral. Go with your plan.