# different wiring in newly purchased ceiling fixture

Tags: wiring

Purchased a new ceiling light fixture.  The new fixture only has a copper ground wire and a black wire that is partially "split" into two wires (and since it is a very long wire, I believe it is to be cut to the needed length and then split.  How do I wire this to the typical black and white wiring (and ground wire) that is coming out of the ceiling?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Is there any chance you could post some pictures of the fan and wires in question?

Comment: Or give specifics about the manufacturer and model, or give an URL to it online.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Have the answer.  Did not realize one black was ribbed (the neutral) and one was not (black to black connection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a light fixture has two wires of the same color it usually means that polarity isn't important. However, the ridges/ribs may indicate a neutral. Connect them to the black and white wiring accordingly.

Possible duplicate [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/93323/how-should-this-light-fixture-be-connected).

Comment: Thank you for your response.  You are correct. Did not realize that one black was ribbed and the other was not.  According to the included (almost worthless) installation pictures, the ribbed wire is the neutral.  Now my installation should go without a hitch.